# What should be the approach for react js based site's performance testing-Jmeter

Tags: jmeter, tableau-api, performance-testing

I have an application which is in react js. Here I am giving demo site  https://webix.com/demos/bank-app/#!/top/customers?user=1/information .Suppose I have to do performance test of statistics page tab how can I do this. As all the resources downloaded from the start when I hit the ttps://webix.com/demos/bank-app/ page. Now when I go to chrome developer tool and click on customer->statistics it shows me only static file.my client wants me to check the performance of those chart load time.

can anybody help.

Also do I have to load test google API's for charts that loaded on the page. There is so many SVG files and woff2 file. do I have to load test these things.[image]

Thanks,
Bibek

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`client wants me to check the performance of those chart load time` - if you mean chart **rendering** time - JMeter won't give this to you, as per [JMeter project main page](https://jmeter.apache.org/):

> JMeter is not a browser, it works at protocol level. As far as web-services and remote services are concerned, JMeter looks like a browser (or rather, multiple browsers); however JMeter does not perform all the actions supported by browsers. In particular, JMeter does not execute the Javascript found in HTML pages. **Nor does it render the HTML pages as a browser does** (it's possible to view the response as HTML etc., but the timings are not included in any samples, and only one sample in one thread is ever displayed at a time).

So if you want to include this rendering time into your report the only option I can think of is going for [WebDriver Sampler](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/WebDriverSampler/) which provides JMeter integration with [Selenium](https://www.selenium.dev/) browser automation framework

`There is so many SVG files and woff2 file. do I have to load test these things.` - yes, but wisely, there is a special setting at "Avanced" tab of the [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler responsible for retrieval of these images, scripts, styles, fonts, etc.

[image]

the idea is to enable downloading for the domain you're testing (and exclude external assets if any). Also don't forget to add [HTTP Cache Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cache_Manager) to your test plan because real browsers do download these "embedded resources" but they do it only once. See [Web Testing with JMeter: How To Properly Handle Embedded Resources in HTML Responses](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/web-testing-jmeter-how-properly-handle-embedded-resources-html-responses) article for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Try Google lighthouse once. It will give brief idea about basic improvement. By this you can achieve good amount performance improvement. then you can go with JMeter.